# Exclude path from checkstyle-plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Eclipse 2018-12
Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in 8.12.0
Java jdk11.0.1

In my eclipse projects, i use Google’s auto-value. Files are autogenerated in /projectRoot/.apt_generated/tld/domain/some/package/AutoValue_AnyName.java. I want to exclude those files from checkstyle checks, so i added

```
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value=".*/.apt_generated/.*/AutoValue_.*"/>
</module>
```

in my checkstyle.xml. IMO, that should match the autogenerated files and exclude them from scanning. Alas, Eclipse’s opinion differs. The files are scanned, and Google does not follow my coding style, so i get a lot of “Problems”. How can i exclude those files from checkstyle?

Comment: Double check your folder path (`/` versus \\) and the `.apt` portion (I assume you mean `\.apt`. If that doesn't work try making the pattern exclude everything and work backwords to your specific file/folder.

Comment: I tried /, \ and \\ (because the \ is the escape character in regexps), nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude from checking by adding this to your project's `.checkstyle` file:

```
<fileset-config file-format-version="1.2.0" simple-config="true" sync-formatter="false">
  ...
  <filter name="DerivedFiles" enabled="true" />
</fileset-config>
```

This assumes that AutoValue/APT is marking the generated files as derived.

Or if your generated types are restricted to a particular folder/package:

```
<fileset-config file-format-version="1.2.0" simple-config="true" sync-formatter="false">
  ...
  <filter name="FilesFromPackage" enabled="true">
    <filter-data value="derived" />
  </filter>
</fileset-config>
```

Or you can try:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/.checkstyleSuppress.xml" />
</module>
```

with an appropriate supress xml file.  It is very versatile but takes some work to set up for the first time.

Comment: Since i just lack the time to test all those propositions, i decided to select files externally. I exclude generated files from checkstyle in eclipse, and i just select src/java/main in gradle.